# call each value of an object pointfree

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I've an object of functions:

```
const src = {
  foo: str => str.toUpperCase(),
  bar: str => str + str,
  baz: str => str.split(''),
}
```

And I want to map the object to call each value with a given parameter, like:

```
R.map(R.callTheCurrentProperty('something'))(src)
```

to obtain:

```
{
  foo: 'SOMETHING',
  bar: 'somethingsomething',
  baz: ['s', 'o', 'm', 'e', 't', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'g'],
}
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be ES6 shorthand for `{ foo: foo, ... }`?

Comment: Yep, you are right, I will format the question more explicitly

Comment: Even though it's not sexy functional programming, `for (let p in src) src[p] = src[p]('something')` will do…

Comment: ‘R.map(x => x('something'))(src)‘ will do, but i'm trying to do it pointfree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const applyStr = R.applySpec(src);
const result = applyStr('something');
```